# How to automatically see updated GitHub repo in desktop?

Tags: github

I cloned a GitHub repo to my desktop and then uploaded files to my branch directly on GitHub, but I do not see these uploaded files on my desktop. I view the files through Vs Code too. How can I see the updated files in this GitHub repo on my desktop? I want the updates to automatically sync on both sides

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to get updated code from `your_branch_name`:

```
git pull origin your_branch_name
```

For more details visit this [git command reference](https://github.com/joshnh/Git-Commands).

Comment: I want to see the updated code from my branch of the repo, not the main branch

Comment: git pull origin your_branch_name

Answer (score 0):

Can't - If the files you uploaded have the same file name as the files in the clone then you will not see additional files, the only thing you can see is the diff.

(DIFF DESCRIPTION: Show changes between the working tree and the index of a tree, changes between the index and a tree, changes between two trees, changes resulting from a merge, changes between two blob objects, or changes between two files on disk. git diff [] )

when you do a git commit, use the -a flag over the -m flag, -a will show all the files that have been edited.

SourceTree, Git Cola and GitHub Desktops are all viable options.

If you don't use GUI, learn the git diff commands. Hope this is somewhat helpful.